A divergent Euler sequence example when using ODE Euler's Method
Usually, we can construct an polygonal curve by using Euler's Method to solve ODE. When reading ODE textbook, I noticed an example showing that Euler polygonal curve can be not convergent sometimes:

Assume that function $\alpha(x)$ satisfies $\alpha(0)=0$ and $\alpha(x)=\int_0^x \mathrm{e}^{-1 / x^2} \mathrm{~d} x \quad(0<x \leqslant 1)$.
And define continuous function $$
f^*(x, y)= \begin{cases}x, & 0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1, y>\alpha(x) \\ x \cos \frac{\pi}{x}, & 0<x \leqslant 1, y=0 \\ -x, & 0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1, y<-\alpha(x)\end{cases}
$$ in the strip closed area $G:0\le x\le 1,-\infty<y<+\infty$.
Next, we consider the condition $$\begin{cases}y'=f(x,y)\\ y(0)=0\end{cases}$$
Divide the interval $[0,1]$ into $n$ parts and construct a polygonal curve $y=\phi_n(x)(0\le x\le 1)$ using Euler's Method.
Now when $\frac1n\le x\le1$, we have:

If $n$ is even, then $\phi_n(x)\ge \alpha(x)$;
If $n$ is odd, then $\phi_n(x)\le -\alpha(x)$.

So we know the Euler sequence $\{\phi_n(x)\}$ isn't convergent.


I have read this example from 3 different books. (So probably it's right) But I still have a question that I think $y(\frac1n)$ should be $0$ because of $f(0,0)=0$ (so that the initial slope should be $0$). If true, then $y$ satisfies neither of them:


If $n$ is even, then $\phi_n(x)\ge \alpha(x)$;
If $n$ is odd, then $\phi_n(x)\le -\alpha(x)$.


Then the example is not true. Is there something wrong here? Or just this example is wrong?
